# Prolog - resolution

Tags: prolog, logic, resolution

I am doing resolution proof in formal logic using truth table and prolog program outcome of my experiments are different and I want to know why.

Here is the problem in plain english:
1. If someone looks into eyes of fighter, he is going to get angry.
2. If the fighter gets angry, he is going to punch.

If the fighter punched, did someone look into fighter's eyes?

'Fighter punched' is conclusion, and we know when conclusion is true the premise could be either false or true, therefore we can't answer the question.

However, following SWI prolog program returns true:

```
eyes:-angry.
angry:-punch.
punch.
?-eyes.
True
```

Also

```
aggregate_all(count, (eyes), Count) 
1
```

Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `:-` in Prolog is supposed to look like an arrow — an arrow *from right to left*, like `<==`. (We do not actually use an arrow, so that users can freely define a custom operator and use it for their own purpose without interfering with regular Prolog code.)

Thus, all your arrows point in the wrong direction. You probably meant:

```
angry(true) :- eyes(true).

punch(true) :- angry(true).
```

I am introducing a Boolean argument for these predicates so that you can play with different parameters without worrying about (non)existence of any predicates.

For example, if you add to these clauses:

```
eyes(true).
```

Then you get:

```
?- punch(T).
T = true.
```

However, if you instead add:

```
eyes(false).
```

then you get:

```
?- punch(T).
false.
```

This shows that yes, someone must have looked the person in the eye.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how the prolog works - it's been a while. However, I   think answer to the question 'If the fighter punched, did someone look into fighter's eyes?'  can not be answered, because the truth -fighter punched is still in conclusion.

    angry(true) :- eyes(true).
    punch(true) :- angry(true).
    punch(true).
    ?-eyes(T)
No answer

Comment: From the output I showed, you know that if nobody looked the fighter into the eyes, then no punch occurred. Ergo, if the fighter *has* punched, then someone must have looked the fighter into the eyes. By the way, you should also really look into CLP(B) constraints, available for example in SICStus Prolog, GNU Prolog etc., to model the task over Boolean variables, where you can state all requirements easily and look for solutions too.